# Angular 10 : ngOnInit two promises

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, promise, angularfire2

I'm currently trying to implement in my Angular app the connection to Strava API.

To resume quickly:

1. User clicks on a button to connect to Strava
2. It is redirected to Strava for authentication(using PKCE)
3. Strava redirects to my app with a code
4. In the ngoninit I'm checking for route params and if I have the code, I launch two promises chained: the first one to get the Access Token from Strava then the recording into a DB(Firebase).

The problem is that sometimes the data is recorded in firebase and sometimes it is not. The behavior is not systematic. Strange thing is that I go into my *postNewToken* everytime because the console logs it.

- If I just record to firebase (without strava token request) in ngOnInit(), it is created in 100% of the cases.
- If I have a button that launches the token request and record into firebase, it seems to work everytime.

I have no idea how to solve it. It seems more a question of chaining promises into ngOnInit but I have no idea even how to bypass it.

The code from my component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
        const stravaCode = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('code');
        if (stravaCode !== undefined) {
          this.stravaService.handleStravaAuthorizationCode(stravaCode);
}
```

And in the service associated:

```
 // Handle Strava Code received
 handleStravaAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode: string) {
     this.getStravaToken(authorizationCode).then(res => {
       this.postNewToken(res).then(res => {
         this.router.navigate(['encoding']);
       });
     });
 }

 // Get Strava access token to make the requests to the API -> only done once
 getStravaToken(authorizationCode: string){
   if (authorizationCode !== undefined){
     console.log('Authorization code: ' + authorizationCode);

     const data = {
       client_id: environment.strava.client_id,
       client_secret: environment.strava.client_secret,
       code: authorizationCode,
       grant_type: 'authorization_code'
     };

     return this.http.post<StravaToken>(this.stravaTokenURL, data)
     .pipe(catchError(this.errorService.handleHttpError)).toPromise();
   }
 }

 postNewToken(stravaToken: StravaToken) {
   if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
       console.log('Recording strava token into Firebase');
       console.log(stravaToken);
       return this.afs.collection('strava_tokens')
       .add(stravaToken).then(res => console.log(res), err => console.log(err));
   } else {
       return Promise.reject(new Error('No User Logged In!'));
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can u handle error cases as well and console the error s inside reject handleStravaAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode: string) {
     this.getStravaToken(authorizationCode).then(res => {
       this.postNewToken(res).then(res => {
         this.router.navigate(['encoding']);
       },err=>console.log(err));
     },err=>console.log(err));
 }

Comment: If I do this:
  handleStravaAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode: string) {
      this.getStravaToken(authorizationCode).then(res => {
        this.postNewToken(res).then(res => {
          this.router.navigate(['encoding']);
        }, err => console.log('Err1:'+err));
      }, err => console.log('Err2:'+err));
  }
-> 
I have no error in the console

Comment: Can u try this    handleStravaAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode: string) {
     this.getStravaToken(authorizationCode).then(async res => {
     res = await   this.postNewToken(res);
         this.router.navigate(['encoding']);
      
     });
 }

Comment: I tried, but still no effect ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I understood.
I simply was not waiting for the connection to firebase to be established. So, I could not post any new data because I was not authenticated.